# Is it possible to change the html/css of a page permanently?

Tags: html, dom

As in, if I go into the developer console and I want to delete all of a some element such as blockquotes , is there a way to save that change locally so that each time I return to the page the blockquotes wouldn't appear again.

Comment: Not in any browser that I know of. Typically this sort of client-side page manipulation is handled using the [GreaseMonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/) (Firefox) or [TamperMonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/) (Chrome/Edge) extensions.

Comment: No, those blockquotes could be sent by the webserver and defined there. So each time you refresh the page you will get those blockquotes again and again

Answer (score 0):

You can get the extension called: [Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha) and use it's basic features or edit css of the webpage yourself. This will make sure every-time the extension is enabled you will have these effects permanently on your browser. I have changed so many elements and used this to see a live preview of css I've added to make styled pages.